# Text Similarity between two dataframe of unequal size

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have two dataframe containing id and embedding of text, I wanted to check the similarity on cross dataframe. The length of data1(2000) is less than data2(0.5 million).

I wanted to the similarity between each row to all rows of data2 like row1 of data1 to all rows of data2 and row2 of data1 to all rows of data2 and so on.

For each iteration, I wanted to store the best matching and ID from both columns.

```
data1
ID_1, title_embeddings
1, 'dbhbhbc jcdwc dnwc, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8
2, 'hbwdbhbc jcdwc dnwc, 0.15, 0.65, 0.85, 0.348
..

data2
ID_2, text1, tweet_embeddings
1, 'dbhbc jcdwc dnwc, '0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8
2, 'dbhbc jcdwc dnwc, 0.15, 0.65, 0.85, 0.348
3, 'dbhbnec jcdwc dnwc, 0.565, 0.346, 0.28, 0.18
4, 'dbhbc jcdwc dnwc, 0.165, 0.365, 0.785, 0.348
```

```py
X=data2['title_embeddings']
Y=data1.head()

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import spatial

for i, row in Y.iterrows():
   print('number ' +str(i))
   sim_score=[]
   for j in range(0,len(X)):
       a= 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(row['tweet_embeddings'], X[j])
       sim_score.append(a)
       print(max(sim_score))
```

```
Expected output
ID_1, ID_2, tweet_embeddings, sim_score
1      4    'dbhbc jcdwc dnwc, 0.5
```

Currently, I am not able to find the result with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output first needs the similarity score, which can be computed as below. However, in **data1**, is that the idf score in third row?

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

df_cos_sim = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.index)
res = data1.tweet_embeddings # this needs to be in matrix form

# 0.5 million rows of data2
for i in range(500000):
    current_cosine_sim = linear_kernel(res[i:i+1], res).flatten()
    df_cos_sim[i] = current_cosine_sim
    
df_cos_sim
```